# Openshift 3 CronJob inside running container

Tags: php, laravel, cron, openshift, scheduler

If I understand it correctly, you can configure Openshift to run cronjobs which will run a job periodically. Also a job seems to run a new container each time the cronjob fires.

I need a way to run a command each minute, but inside a running container/pod/deployment instead of creating a new container each time.
We use Openshift to deploy our php 7 / Laravel application. This framework uses an inbuilt scheduler. To make it work, you have to trigger the framework each minute with "php artisan run".

As far as I understand, one should not alter the container image (php+apache) to include a cron service. But how should I do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a somewhat *unconventional* solution to this. OpenShift/Kubernetes has the concept of ["Application Health Checks"](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/application_health.html). This is basically something that the platform runs every so often (as defined) and can either make an HTTP call, TCP connection, or **perform an action within the container**. The side effect to this is that the command run in the container *fails*, your pod will be restarted. This is generally used to check if an application is no longer responsive and to allow the platform to kill it off and restart.

But, it can totally be bastardized to do exactly what you need, and doesn't require using the CronJobs, which are currently only available in Tech Preview.

You should be able to run the following, which will `patch` your current DeploymentConfig to include a `livenessProbe` that will run `php artisan run` every minute:

`oc patch dc/<deployment-name> -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"<deployment-name>","livenessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/bash","-c","php","artisan","run","||","true"]},"initialDelaySeconds":60,"periodSeconds":60,"timeoutSeconds":120}}]}}}}'`

> Note that you'll need to provide the `deployment-name` twice in the above command.

This will tell OpenShift to run `/bin/bash -c php artisan run || true` 60 seconds after the pod is started, continue to run every 60 seconds, and consider it a failure if the command takes longer than 120 seconds to run. If the command times out more than 3 times, the pod will be considered unhealthy and restarted (`|| true` ensures that even if the command fails, it'll won't kill the pod).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to create a livenessProbe via the UI of openshift. The only thing I had to change was the periodSeconds (via yaml) because there is no such option in the UI (default is 10 seconds). Till today I built another solution by creating a deployment of a custom images which logs into openshift via the oc binary, filters all pods by a specific label (laravel=uses-scheduler) and then does a oc exec on the filtered pods. Anyway, your solution is much more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to append to this question as I just got this to work with Openshift's native cron job feature. This feature builds a new pod using an existing image of your choice, runs a command of your choice (in this case, "php artisan schedule:run") and then shuts down the pod. This is outlined in the online docs for Openshift. I use YAML along with the "Import to project using YAML/JSON" option in the interface to create the pod. If I need to delete the cron job, I use "oc delete cronjob/myCron" in the CLI.

Here is the example YAML:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: myCron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
  jobTemplate:             
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:          
            parent: "myCron"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: myCron
            image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/adv-dev/myApplication
            command: [php, artisan, "schedule:run"]
            envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: my-config-map
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

To note:

- The myCron is an arbitrary name, but use something specific to the application that needs the cron to run.
- "*/1 * * * *" is the classic crontab schedule format. Here, it's setting the job to run once a minute.
- The image "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/adv-dev/myApplication" is the existing image for the pod that needs the cron. Remember, this cron job won't run in the existing pod. Instead, openshift will spin up a new pod using that same image with the exact same codebase and run the command line in that new pod. After it runs openshift will tear down the cron job pod leaving a history with logs to view. By default, the 3 most recent pod histories will be kept.
- The envFrom section is where you inject your env vars (DB/SMTP usernames/passwords etc.) for the cron job pod. They need to be a config map so they can be imported and available to the code. This means you can also use the same config maps in the "permanent" pod running your application to avoid duplication.